# Remmina 1.4.25 mic not working when connecting to windows 11

Tags: remmina

I'm trying to connect via remmina to a windows 11 host, audio works fine, it detects the mic but the mic doesn't work. It appears on windows input devices as Remote Audio for both input and output.

My remmina sound client options are as follows:

- Audio output mode: Local
- Redirect local audio output: *blank*
- Redirect local microphone: *blank*

I have PulseAudio 15.99.1, rebooted after install, but haven't rebooted windows host. Any help is appreciated!!